# Python environment always killed immediately after importing libraries

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1

Here is an example of the given problem. This started occurring after I killed a jupyter lab session and now every time I try to start a new jupyter hub or jupyter notebook branch the session is immediately killed. Same goes for when I try to load python modules.

Please help[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CTEX.png)

Comment: have you tried to restart your machine?

Comment: yes, twice. But to no avail